# Password comparison returns error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `Users` table with a `password` column defined thus:

`password           | text                     | not null`

And a SQLAlchemy model defined thus:

`password = db.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['bcrypt'], max_length=128), nullable=False)`

I can successfully insert a row using this model:

```
user = Users(first_name='James', last_name='Bond', password='aaa')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

But when selecting the row back I can't compare the password:

```
user = db.session.query(Users).join(ContactDetails).\
            filter(ContactDetails.email == 'james.bond@gmail.com').first()
assert user.password == 'aaa'
```

This results in the following error:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../../.virtualenvs/amazon_sales/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/password.py:60: in __eq__
    valid, new = self.context.verify_and_update(value, self.hash)
../../../../.virtualenvs/amazon_sales/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/context.py:2417: in verify_and_update
    record = self._get_or_identify_record(hash, scheme, category)
../../../../.virtualenvs/amazon_sales/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/context.py:2026: in _get_or_identify_record
    return self._identify_record(hash, category)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <passlib.context._CryptConfig object at 0x10f5e7090>, hash = '\\x2432622431322457475a794c4e4a5973704e4f7750444b322e3766302e336c58365778506e7050767a2e6f394d317748716650717174796a6e4d3475'
category = None, required = True

    def identify_record(self, hash, category, required=True):
        """internal helper to identify appropriate custom handler for hash"""
        # NOTE: this is part of the critical path shared by
        #       all of CryptContext's PasswordHash methods,
        #       hence all the caching and error checking.
        # FIXME: if multiple hashes could match (e.g. lmhash vs nthash)
        #        this will only return first match. might want to do something
        #        about this in future, but for now only hashes with
        #        unique identifiers will work properly in a CryptContext.
        # XXX: if all handlers have a unique prefix (e.g. all are MCF / LDAP),
        #      could use dict-lookup to speed up this search.
        if not isinstance(hash, unicode_or_bytes_types):
            raise ExpectedStringError(hash, "hash")
        # type check of category - handled by _get_record_list()
        for record in self._get_record_list(category):
            if record.identify(hash):
                return record
        if not required:
            return None
        elif not self.schemes:
            raise KeyError("no crypt algorithms supported")
        else:
>           raise ValueError("hash could not be identified")
E           ValueError: hash could not be identified

../../../../.virtualenvs/amazon_sales/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/context.py:1131: ValueError
```

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the passwords in the same way they are entered, or is there extra char appended to the password at the time of committing, resulting in mismatch at the time of comparison?

Answer (score 0):

The point of using bcrypt is to **not** store the plaintext password in the database. Instead a ~hash of the password is stored (if this is not clear to you, you should read the documentation of `PasswordType` and the [OWASP Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet) and make sure you understand it.)

What you're doing is storing a bcrypt'ed password through SQLAlchemy magic, and comparing that to the plaintext password:

```
assert user.password == 'aaa'
```

while you should be bcrypt'ing the password and comparing the result to what is stored in the database. Have a look at `bcrypt.hashpw`.

Comment: Look closely at the password type I use in the model ;)

Comment: `PasswordType(schemes=['bcrypt'] ... ` ?

Comment: Exactly, that changes everything.